# Solving an asymptotic equation

Tags: real-analysis, asymptotics, laplace-method

Suppose for $t$ in some neighborhood $(0,\delta)$, we define $s>0$ via
$$
\frac{a_2}{2!}t^2+\frac{a_3}{3!}t^3+\cdots=-s^2
$$
where $\{a_2,a_3,\ldots\}$ is such that $a_2<0$ and the LHS above converges. Then, why is it true that
$$
t=\left\{\frac{-2}{a_2}\right\}^{1/2}s+O(s^2)?
$$
This appears as equation (2.27) in Murray (1984)'s Asymptotic Analysis. How did the author obtain this result? I looked at
\begin{align*}
\frac{t-[-2/a_2]^{1/2}s}{s^2}&=\frac{t}{-(\frac{a_2}{2!}t^2+\frac{a_3}{3!}t^3+\cdots)}-\frac{[-2/a_2]^{1/2}}{s}\\
&=\frac{1}{-(\frac{a_2}{2!}t+\frac{a_3}{3!}t^2+\cdots)}-\frac{[-2/a_2]^{1/2}}{s}
\end{align*}
but couldn't complete the justification.

Comment: You can solve these kind of questions as: assume $t=\sum_{k=1}^\infty \;  \alpha_k s^k$, you replace it in your equation and balance the powers of $s$ on both sides. You immediately recover your result.

Comment: @Chip With your suggestion, I can work out $\alpha_k=(-2/a_2)^{1/2}$ and then the claim follows. Why does your method work? Specifically, why do we start with $\sum_{k=1}^\infty\alpha_ks^k$ as opposed to $\sum_{k=0}^\infty\alpha_ks^k$? Could you please point to a reference? I'm grateful for your help. And of course, if you write things as an answer, I will + and tick.

Comment: I have posted a more detailed answer, as you requested. Hope it helps. The power series method is quite standard, maybe you can check older books on asymptotics like http://www.amazon.com/Asymptotic-Methods-Analysis-Dover-Mathematics/dp/0486642216 or Erdelyi http://www.amazon.com/Asymptotic-Expansions-Dover-Books-Mathematics/dp/0486603180/. Also, books on perturbation theory help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By looking at the equality, on the LHS (left-hand side) we have the smallest power of $t$ being $t^2$, while on the RHS we have $s^2$. Assuming that $t$ can be written as a power series of $s$ (convergent and/or asymptotic), we immediately notice that the first power of $s$ in the series $t=\sum \alpha_k s^k$ must be $k=1$ (the $k=0$ term would be a constant that does not depend on $s$ in the LHS, while there is no such constant in the RHS of the original equation). Hence, we have $t=\sum_{k=1}^\infty \alpha_k s^k$. Now, by equating the coefficients of the same powers of $s$ on the LHS and RHS, we immediately obtain the result for the first term, $\alpha_1$.

I believe this is a somewhat of a standard method for such problems, and is similar to methods encountered in the context of perturbation theory https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perturbation_theory or somewhat similar to the method of dominant balance https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asymptotic_analysis#Method_of_dominant_balance.

Answer (score 1):

Another way is
to consider
$\frac{a_2}{2!}t^2+\frac{a_3}{3!}t^3+\cdots=-s^2
$
as an iteration
$\dfrac{-s^2}{t^2}
=\frac{a_2}{2!}+\frac{a_3}{3!}t+\cdots
$
or
$t^2
=\dfrac{-s^2}{\dfrac12 a_2+\dfrac16 a_3 t+\cdots}
$.

With a first estimate
of $t^2 = 0$,
this gets
$t^2
=\dfrac{-s^2}{\dfrac12 a_2}
=\dfrac{-2s^2}{ a_2}
$.

Putting this in,
we get

$\begin{array}\\
t^2
&=\dfrac{-s^2}{\dfrac12 a_2+\dfrac16 a_3 \sqrt{\dfrac{-2s^2}{ a_2}}+O(s^2)}\\
&=\dfrac{-s^2}{\dfrac12 a_2(1+O(s))}\\
&=\dfrac{-2s^2}{ a_2}(1+O(s))\\
\text{so}\\
t
&=\sqrt{\dfrac{-2s^2}{ a_2}}\sqrt{(1+O(s))}\\
&=\sqrt{\dfrac{-2s^2}{a_2}}(1+O(s))\\
&=\sqrt{\dfrac{-2s^2}{a_2}}+O(s^2)\\
\end{array}
$

These kind of results
always need to be checked,
so let's see what we get.

First,
note that the estimate
gives the cruder approximation
$t = O(s)$.
This is useful because
we want to use
the crudest approximation
that will give the
same error terms
everywhere.

The crude estimate gives
$\frac{a_3}{3!}t^3+\cdots
=\frac{a_3}{3!}s^3+\cdots
=O(s^3)
$
and the more accurate estimate gives
$\frac12 a_2t^2
=\frac12 a_2 (\dfrac{-2s^2}{ a_2}(1+O(s)))
=-s^2(1+O(s))
=-s^2+O(s^3)
$.

Adding these,
$\frac12 a_2t^2+\frac{a_3}{3!}t^3+\cdots
=-s^2+O(s^3)
$,
which is what we want.

Comment: I'm a bit shaky with the bit where you get $t^2=-2s^2/a_2$ and then you replace  $\frac{1}{2}a_2+\frac{1}{6}a_3t+\cdots$ with $\frac{1}{2}a_2+\frac{1}{6}a_3\sqrt{-2s^2/a_2}+O(s^2)$. Could you please elaborate? I can follow the algebra but I don't know why it is legitimate to do what you do.

Comment: You start with the assumption that $t$ is small, so the initial approximation is $t=0$. This gives the first approximation. The next substitution gives  stated approximation. I will add a statement about checking the result.